# selecting vertices with the alt key

Tags: modeling

I selected a UV sphere cut it in half in the edit mode then tried to select all the vertices on the lower rig by holding down alt key and clicking on one vertice. Can't select all the
vertices.I am using blender version 3.2.2

Comment: If you want to select a whole part, put your mouse over this part and press L, or if you've already selected on vertex of this part, press Ctrl L, not sure about the Alt click you're doing

Comment: Clicking with the Alt key held down is used to select a loop of verts. As @monboots says you need Ctrl-L to select the whole part.